# Why are some updated list items not being saved?

Tags: 2013, list, save

So I'm a basic administrator for our team Sharepoint 2013 Site.
We have made a list for some of the users to track their progress which they will periodically update.

Now its update season again and several people have had the following issues.
They update their items, save them, only for the changes to be gone!

This of course is highly annoying because basically I have to tell them to redo all their work.
As of yet I cant work out what's causing the issue, and therefore I can't fix it!
Any suggestions?
As a sidenote; we are still running IE9, just thought about that.

Comment: What actually you want? even aftrer the update of item you want both old and new item? Can you please be more clear about your question

Comment: I want the new item. The changes are mysteriously gone

Comment: What happens when you update the old item?

Comment: For some users it reverts back to the old item, also, when I check the last modified date, no modifications seem to have been made. So lets say the last time the item was updated was June 17th, and they changed it today. If it failed for them, the Last modified date will still be June 17th

Answer (score 1):

The issue **may be** caused by the **versioning settings** for the list.

If **Require content approval** for submitted items in **versioning settings** for the list is **selected**, then you can decide **who can view the draft items**.

It depends on the user's permission that they can see draft item in the list.

[image]

**Resolution**

So if you want to make the users be able to view the draft items, you need to give then enough permission in the list or you can select Any user who can read items or disable the content approval function in the list.

If this is not the case than kindly let me know.

Comment: Sadly, this is not the case. Whilst I do use versioning, I dont require it to be approved first